# Php how to check multiple times (within `foreach`) if values from array exists in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, foreach

How to check multiple times (within `foreach`) if values from three arrays exists in three mysql columns?

One way `SELECT`, fetch whole column and create array with the column values. Then `(in_array($value_to_check[$i], $whole_mysql_column)`.

Other way would be multiple `SELECT Column FROM Table WHERE Column = ?` and `?` is `$value_to_check[$i]`

Suppose both ways uses much resources. Is there better way?

Comment: the latter would be the more efficient.

Comment: But, if for example 1000 `SELECT`... not good.

Comment: yes you completely right. for some range of low numbers it would be better then at some point indeed the former will become better. I don't think there is any other way than the 2 you have put.

Comment: How are the three arrays you are wanting to check against the three mysql columns created, and where does the data come from?

Comment: The 3 arrays comes from excel file (php receives data from excel). If you can click on `edit` below the question, you may see initial long question, where I described all process.

Answer (score 2):

Why make so much queries to begin with? Why not make a single giant SQL query that uses IN instead, e.g.

```
$sqlValuesToCheck = '(';
foreach ($value_to_check as $value) {
    $sqlValueToCheck .= "'" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($value) . "',";
}
$sqlValueToCheck = rtrim($sqlValueToCheck, ',') . ')';

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `Column` FROM `Table` WHERE `Column` IN {$sqlValueToCheck}");
```

The above will get all `Table`.`Column` values that are also in the array. You mentioned that you'd like to check 3 columns... depending on how you want to use the result, you could use a UNION or simply list the other columns before the FROM.

Comment: Will experiment with advice. Thanks